# Ruby: undefined method `assert'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

I follow this code on codeschool

**string_extension_test.rb**

```
gem "minitest", "~> 4.0"
require "test/unit"
require "string_extension"

assert "3".is_number?
assert !"Blash".is_number?
```

**string_extension.rb**

```
class String 
    def is_number?
        if self =~/^\d+$/
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end
end
```

And I type `ruby -I. string_extension_test.rb`

However, it shows that

```
string_extension_test.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method `assert' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I have tried add `include Test::Unit::Assertions` in **string_extension_test.rb**, it can pass, but no test case.

the output will be

```
Finished tests in 0.013038s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You likely need to put your tests inside a class which inherits from Test::Unit::TestCase. Something like:

```
class StringExtensionTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_is_number
    assert '3'.is_number?
  end

  def test_is_not_number
    assert !'B'.is_number?
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, you have been a great help.

Answer (score 5):

Put your tests in a class... ensure the methods start with the string "test"...

```
gem "minitest", "~> 4.0"
require 'test/unit'
require 'calc'
class TestStringExtension < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_is_number?
      assert "3".is_number?
      assert !"Blash".is_number?
    end
end
```